# Export 3ds max object in 360 degree images

Tags: jquery, flash, 3d, 3ds

I created a 3d object in 3ds max that reprezent a fence/Wall. How can I export image files from each angle (or from 10 to 10 degrees)?

With thoose images I want to create a web 360 degrees image display plugin.

Here is a example from my fence:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a few years back, I linked a target camera to a shape object above my target and wrote a simple max script which rotated the shape object in increments and rendered an image after each rotation.
I don't have the script now, but it was super easy, the web is full with max-script examples

```
t = 0;
while t < 360 do
(
    Object.rotation.x_rotation = t;
    render camera:$cameraName frame:1 outputfile:"somePath_" + t as string + ".png"
    t = t + 1;
)
```

something like that

however, you could use stage3d and flair3d or alternativa 3d to display 3d. that way you'll have free camera movements in your app and you'll have much smaller file size, since instead of 60, 180, 360 images, you would load just the geometry and the textures